# Как проверить, принадлежит ли точка четырехугольнику?

Tags: python, геометрия

К примеру у меня есть следующие точки, образующие 4-ех угольник.

```
x1 = 81.0582
y1 = 348.106
x2 = 127.111
y2 = 367.577
x3 = 120
y3 = 256
x4 = 166.053
y4 = 275.471
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По условию не дано, какая из этих точек верхняя вершина или нижняя. Это несложно вычислить и я это сделал. Но дело в том, что четырехугольник лежит под углом и это усложняет задачу. Подскажите, какой алгоритм использовать, чтобы узнать, принадлежит ли точка (любая) четырехугольнику или нет?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5922027/7485582

Comment: Честно говоря, решения по этой ссылке далеки от идеала.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно провести из проверяемой точки любой луч и сосчитать сколько раз он пересекается со сторонами четырехугольника. Точка находится внутри если это число нечётное.

Для определённости можно выбрать горизонтальный луч направленный вправо. Вам понадобится одна примитивная операция - проверка пересечения горизонтального луча и отрезка. "Примитивная" - это термин, который не означает что эта операция простая. :)

Тонкий момент когда луч проходит через вершину четырехугольника, надо будет тщательно обработать этот случай.

Подробности тут:

[Задача о принадлежности точки многоугольнику](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83#%D0%A3%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9).

[Проверка принадлежности точки многоугольнику](http://algolist.ru/maths/geom/belong/poly2d.php).